# C# HttpWebRequest Request Connection Close

Tags: c#, http, connection, httprequest

Why still waiting the response from Httprequest ? How to close the connection ? Get 100-continue always!

```
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.193/login.aspx");

    var postData = "Login=A@Pass=B";
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
    request.Method = "POST"; //01
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    //request.Connection ="Close"; 
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10; //02
    request.Host = "192.168.0.193"; //03
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0"; //04
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; //05
    request.ContentLength = data.Length; //05
    request.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache"); //06
    request.Accept = "*/*"; //07



    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Close();              
    }

    request.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);            

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are waiting because "login.aspx" is not sending back a HttpResponse. Since no HttpResponse is being returned, the request will just time out. If you want to get a http response you have to write an web service using SOAP or REST protocols. An web service can return a HttpResponse which you can then capture with an WebRequest as you have posted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
```